# Erro Evento ListView para Imagens Redondas

Tags: delphi, listview, firemonkey

Tenho um listview ligdo a um FDMemTable, no evento :

```
TForm31.ListView1UpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject;
const AItem: TListViewItem);
```

eu faço o seguinte procedimento para deixar as fotos redondas :

```
var imagem : TListItemImage;
begin

imagem := AItem.Objects.FindObject('Image_funcionario') as TListItemImage;

Circle1.Fill.Bitmap.Bitmap := imagem.Bitmap;

Image1.Bitmap := Circle1.MakeScreenshot;

TListItemImage(AItem.Objects.FindDrawable('Image_funcionario')).Bitmap := Image1.Bitmap;

end;
```

O problema é o seguinte : Quando carrego novos registros no FDMemTable, a aplicação pula algumas linhas do evento e não deixa as fotos redondas.

Comment: Qual linguagem?

Comment: Olá, Delphi Firemonkey